# Переход к заданной позиции в файле

Tags: c#

Мне нужно считывать символы с указанной позиции(lastIndexChangedSymbol), что бы вернуться в начало предложения, т.к. последний измененный символ является концом предложения. Проблема в том, что позиция в файле почему-то не изменяется. Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку или объясните, в чём причина такого поведения.

```
        int lastIndexChangedSymbol = 270;
        bool marker = true;
        StreamReader Por = new StreamReader("C:/test2.txt");
        while (marker)
        {
            lastIndexChangedSymbol--;
            Por.BaseStream.Position = lastIndexChangedSymbol;
            char Work_With_Symbol = (char)Por.Peek();
            Console.WriteLine(Por.BaseStream.Position);
            if (Work_With_Symbol == '.' || Work_With_Symbol == '!' || Work_With_Symbol == '?' || lastIndexChangedSymbol == 0)
            {
                marker = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Там буфер - лучше не трожь BaseStream.

Comment: Как мне тогда узнать позицию начала предложения? Основная проблема в том, что преподаватель запретил пользоваться массивами, только работа с файлом и не более. Это очень напрягает и усложняет задание.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404267/4928642

Comment: Только читайте второй ответ, который не отмечен - он правильный и в нём подробней расписано, что можно сделать и почему так лучше не делать. Выбранный в вопросе ответ, как правильный, с созданием собственного класса - это лажа полная.

Comment: Да, хорошо. Спасибо всем большое.